# Android: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzeh(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1591)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1562)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5234)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4828)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4711)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:175)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Текст ошибки с отчета гуглМаркета!

Собственно сама ошибка замечена только на одном устройстве 
Android 4.4 (видать и ниже)
Galaxy Note 10.1

Проверялось на нескольких телефонах и планшетах Android 5 и 6

В эмуляторе мне не удалось добиться того же самого, вылек происходит при запуске приложения. Нашел на просторах интернета решение с добавлением в зборщик `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'` но это не помогло... Даже не представляю куда копать далее...

Спасибо!

Comment: Вопрос решон. 

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' - гредл        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" - в тег апликейшен манифеста